# Is the surface of a torus 2-dimensional?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Unless I'm very mistaken, the surface of a torus is 2-dimensional, as is the surface of a sphere. The reason being that being on the surface you can only move in 2 dimensions, up or down is not well defined. If I'm wrong, please explain why.

My friend got rather upset when I told him this, insisting that the surface of a torus is 3-dimensional. I need some compelling arguments to make him see it (given that I am right, I might not be).

Comment: The 2-torus can be embedded into a 3-dimensional space as a manifold, but the definition of dimension on a topological manifold is for what $n$ the patches are homeomorphic to $k^n$ where $k$ is whatever field you are working over. So a 2-torus over $\mathbb{R}$ is a 2-dimensional real manifold. Also note, you can put the 2-torus in any $N$ dimensional space with $N > 3$ as well...

Comment: Is it any different for the 1-torus? I know very little about this subject, only bits and pieces.

Comment: I guess the 1-torus would be a circle

Comment: The $1$-torus is a circle.

Comment: you can use the notion of locally euclidean of certain dimension for a topological space. You can say that a topological space X is locally euclidean of dimension n if for each point x \in X there exist an open neighborhood of x, U, and an homeomorphism which maps U homeomorphically to an open set of R^n. So the Torus, for instance, is locally euclidean of dimension 2

Comment: @JohnMartin Oh ok. I thought the number prefix was according to the number of holes in the surface, thus I thought you were speaking about the pretzel.

Comment: Oh, ha. Sorry about that. I should have clarified. For this conversation, the $n$ will mean the dimension of the thing as a manifold. But here is a simple way to think about it that may or may not be helpful. Take a bunch of pieces of paper, bend them and glue them together into a torus. That tells you that it is 2-dimensional; you can think of each of the pieces of paper as patches that "look like" 2 dimensional Euclidean space. You could also do that and show it to your friend...

Comment: @JohnMartin Exactly. That was the very non-rigorous proof I was thinking of. Essentially I thought this. Place yourself on the surface as a point. You can only move as if you are on a plane. Up and down aren't well-defined anymore, thus 2D. But yeah, your paper construction is much better as it correlated to the definition of a manifold very nicely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $2$-torus can be written as $S^1\times S^1$.  The $2$-torus is often visualized as a doughnut where someone (who was up to no good) ate the insides of the doughnut, leaving just an empty tube.  The problem that you and your friend are having is about what the definition of dimension is.  There is a difference between an embedding and the intrinsic dimension of an object.

I believe your friend is saying that the torus lives inside a three-dimensional space; it can't be put inside a plane, so, as an object, it isn't flat.  In this case, your friend is looking at the smallest space where the object can be embedded.

On the other hand, the intrinsic dimension of the torus is $2$.  The reason for this that, if you look at small patches of the torus, they look like pieces of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (instead of pieces of $\mathbb{R}^3$).  Alternatively, you can see this as the torus is $S^1\times S^1$ which is a product of two one-dimensional objects (circles).

Comment: Damn the man who ate the inside of the doughnut. But yeah, I don't think my friend realises that he thinks of an object and it's surface as the same thing. John Martin made a great suggestion above, using paper and sort of forcing it to a torus shape. That way, every small piece of the surface resembles $\mathbb{R}^2$. Thanks for your answer as well!